# challenge: robots file of ctf (capture the flag)

Tags: ctf

User-agent: *

Disallow: /

Disallow: /index.css

Disallow: /index.js

# This site is unhackable, so I'm going to taunt you a bit with an inaccessible file.

Disallow: /emoji/../../../flag.txt

robots.txt file downloaded for ctf

suggestions?